# How can I receive web server data in an android application?

Tags: android

I have searched for the right way to go and tried them but didnt got the right result. My code is as follows:

```
public String getData(String pc)  throws Exception
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {

         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         String link = "http://107.180.8.153/androidt/check-pin-code.php?user_pincode="+pc;
         URL url = new URL(link);
         HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
         request.setURI(new URI(link));
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
           String line="";

           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
           {
              sb.append(line);
              break;
            }
            in.close();
            return sb.toString();
         }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    }
```

On printing the returned result... I am getting "Exception: null" .. please help

Comment: did you checked data in browser???

Comment: give a sample workable url, i tried but no data in response,https://www.cloudshoppe.in/androidt/check-pin-code.php?user_pincode=110093

Comment: @Androider How did you find `user_pincode`?

Comment: this is a sample pincode not any specific user, is it incorrect

Comment: try https://www.cloudshoppe.in/androidt/check-pin-code.php?user_pincode=751024

Comment: in browser..it is coming..you can check

Comment: yes with this pin it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that your're using some of deprecated methods, like   HttpClient. Therefore, check the below code with better methods as suggested by http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

AsyncTask Class:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {}
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.e("url",urls[0]);

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//        Integer result = 0;
            try {
                /* forming th java.net.URL object */
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

//                 /* optional request header */
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//
//                /* optional request header */
//                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                /* for Get request */
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
//                Toast.makeText(ForgotPassword.this,String.valueOf(statusCode),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;

                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode ==  200) {



                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
//                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

Log.e("result",result);
            JSONArray pin= null;
            try {
                pin = new JSONArray(result);
                String pinValue=   pin.getJSONObject(0).getString("Pin");
                Log.e("pinvalue",pinValue); //this is what you like
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }
```

Don't forget to provide internet permission in manifest.xml.

Thanks

Comment: @RaunakSinghChauhan, thanks, now i'll give you the solution with new and non-depricated methods

Comment: @RaunakSinghChauhan, check the answer which is working from my end, fully tested.